# Rich text editor that has image upload option

Tags: javascript, jquery, rich-text-editor

I am trying to create a Content Management System using Codeigniter. At present I am stuck on finding a text editor that has built-in image upload option (just like in joomla), so that users can insert images in the content from their uploaded images.

I have found so many text editors but haven't found any which has a built-in image upload option.

Could you please suggest an open source Rich text editor that has image upload option?

Answer (score 10):

[TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/)
[Example here](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php). (Image upload: Go to Images -> Klick the "Browse" icon!

[Niceedit](http://www.nicedit.com/)
[Example here](http://www.nicedit.com/demos.php?demo=1)

[CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/)
[Example here](http://ckeditor.com/demo)

I would recommend these 3!

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that TinyMCE and CKEditor require purchase if you want to upload files and Niceedit uploads them to imgur

Comment: [ckeditor](https://support.ckeditor.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002539665-Can-I-include-CKEditor-4-and-CKEditor-5-in-a-commercial-environment-) for commercial projects.

Answer (score 3):

[CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) is always a good solution

See a demo [here](http://ckeditor.com/demo)

Comment: it is not free fro commercial projects

Answer (score 2):

[TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/) in combination with the [MCImageManager](http://www.tinymce.com/enterprise/mcimagemanager.php) plugin is a decent option. I'm biased though because I think TinyMCE is awesome (it's amazingly easy to integrate, for one thing).

Answer (score 1):

You go for tiny mce.It has an image uploading plugin and that you will have to buy from them.
I dont think you will get any editor with free image uploading feature.